# Bottom bracket length without knowing front chainline (fixed gear)

Tags: bottom-bracket, fixed-gear, chainline

I'm wondering if I can find the right bottom bracket axle (or spindle, whatever it's called) with knowing my crank model (Gipiemme Dual Sprint, Velobase says BB should be 113mm) and rear chainline (I think 47mm, I can measure exactly with caliper).

As far as I know I have to use Campagnolo BB's with Gipiemme cranks and I can only order them online from where I live. I don't want to have to send back, order another and on and on ;)

Comment: While I don't know the specifics of your setup, 113mm seems long for a Campa BB. Typical is 102mm - 108mm.

Comment: I agree with zenbike that 113 seems long. But 47mm also seems long! Note that your information about the Campa BB requirement is inaccurate. You can use an ISO BB with that crank.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be right - the seller meant it would be easier to find Campa BB of that length. As far as the main question goes - there is no way of finding out without actually putting on the crank right?

Comment: Campagnolo had two lengths of bottom brackets for the last generation of square taper groups, around 102mm for Chorus/Record and around 110mm for lower groups. But these are Gipiemme, not Campagnolo cranks anyway. I don't know about any other commonly available ISO BBs than Campagnolo, though.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming a replacement is necessary, and not a new build, can you remove the cranks and measure the the spindle length?  You can do it with the BB still installed if the caliper arms are 'deep' enough.

While you are in there with calipers, its probably worth getting the BB Shell diameter and width too.

Another variation is the thread's hand orientation (left/ right).  I forget now side is the variable one.